# Rounding error of binary32

Tags: c++, pointers, precision, ieee-754

As part of a homework, I'm writing a program that takes a float decimal number as input entered from terminal, and return IEEE754 *binary32* of that number AND return 1 if the binary exactly represents the number, 0 otherwise. We are only allowed to use iostream and cmath.

I already wrote the part that returns *binary32* format, but I don't understand how to see if there's rounding to that format.

My idea to see the rounding was to calculate the decimal number back from *binary32* form and compare it with the original number. But I am having difficulty with saving the returned binary32 as some type of data, since I can't use the vector header. I've tried using for loops and `pow`, but I still get the indices wrong.

Also, I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is `df` or `*df`? I wrote the code myself, but I only know that I needed to convert address pointed to `float` to address pointed to `char`.

My other idea was to compare *binary32* and *binary 64*, which gives more precision. And again, I don't know how to do this without using vector?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i ,j;
    float num;

    num = atof(argv[1]);

    char* numf = (char*)(&num);

    for (i = sizeof(float) - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--)
            if (numf[i] & (1 << j)) {
                cout << "1";
            }else{
                cout << "0";
            }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

//////
Update:
Since there's no other way around without using header files, I hard coded for loops to convert *binary32* back to decimal.

Since x = 1.b31b30...b0 * 2^p. One for loop for finding the exponent and one for loop for finding the significand.

Comment: A few suggestions: 1. You might want make certain that your system uses IEEE754 floats before you sink too much time debugging. 2. [Get familiar with endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). 3. Wholeheartedly recommend better names. `d` is utterly non descriptive. It provides no hints to the purpose of `d`. This often slows debugging.

Comment: `df` is a pointer to `char`.  `*df` is the `char` it currently points to. You're allowed to use char pointers to pretend that some larger object is made up of chars.

Comment: @user4581301 yes I agree with I need better descriptive names.

Comment: The purpose of the assignment is probably to get you thinking about how to determine exactness as you're building the value. Determining it afterwards sounds like extra work.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes the extra work did make me think hard on precision and how the computers store numbers. It's a lot of googling and wiki reading since all this is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea: Convert your number `d` back to a string (eg. with `to_string`) and compare it to the input. If the strings are different, there was some loss because of the limitations of `float`.

Of course, this means your input always has to be in the same string format that to_string uses. No additional unneeded 0's, no whitespaces, etc.

...
That said, doing the float conversion without cast (but with manually parsing the input and calculating the IEEE754 bits) is more work initally, but in return, it sovled this problem automatically. And, as noted in the comments, your cast might not work the way you want.

Comment: I'm not sure that `std::to_string` will work.  Without being able to change the number of decimals to display, I'm able to print out 0.1 exactly as inputed even though 0.1 is not exactly representable as a float.

Comment: Hm right, I forgot Rounding/Dragon/Grisu ... then, the hard solution (building manual calculations with digit arrays etc.) seems the only way.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! The messy part are the indices, but I finally got that figured out for the for loops.